# how to override the numberlong() when mongodb output writes documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I am creating JSON docs in MongoDB by using MongoDB o/p step in Pentaho PDI kettle with following structure.

Expected output:

```
{
"lan_id" : -1,
"st_id" : 051
}
```

However I am getting following output as MongoDB is by default is creating NumberLong() wrapper around the numbers -1 and 051. I don't want this and I want the above o/p.

```
{
"lan_id" : NumberLong(-1),
"st_id" : NumberLong(051)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue. However I am yet to ascertain the main reason for this ,since I was running out of time. As a temporal solution I used select values step to change the dataypes to Number and **it worked**.

I would be thankful for letting me know the actual cause if you get to learn it.